# Find the points on the graph of the function that are closest to the given point.

Tags: calculus, optimization

$$f(x)=x^2\ ,\ (0,4)$$

I have attempted to plug this in and found the derivative but can not find the answer.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** This is just a reframed optimization problem. What you're looking to optimize–specifically minimize, in this case, is distance. Remember that the distance formula is $\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$ where one pair of $x$s and $y$s refers to the given point $(0, 4)$, and the other pair, some $x$ and $x^2$, refering to the point $(x, x^2)$ on the function:

$$f(x) = \sqrt{(x-0)^2+(x^2-4)^2}$$

Solve for $f'(x)=0$ and find the minimum(s). These will give you the $x$-coordinates of the closest ordered-pairs.

Comment: Thanks I had used the distance formula, unfortunately I was finding the derivative wrong. Have a good one!

Comment: @Tomtheman9043 Just remember to apply the chain rule for everything inner function when differentiating!

Answer (score 0):

Distance formula!

Let's take a point on $f(x)$, that's $(x,x^2)$.

The distance formula tells us that the closest distance is given by $\sqrt{(x-0)^2+(x^2-4)^2}$.

That simplifies to $\sqrt{x^2+x^4-8x^2+16}=\sqrt{x^4-7x^2+16}=g(x)$.

So for any point $(x,f(x))$, our distance is $g(x)$.

You mentioned a derivative. Let's do that. The derivative should be zero when we get an extrema (minimum/maximum). We have to have a minimum because the function grows infinitely far from the point.

$g'(x) = \displaystyle \frac{4x^3-14x}{2\sqrt{x^4-7x^2+16}}$.

As we can see, $g'(x)=0$ when $4x^3-14x=0$, that's when $x^2=\frac{7}{2}$.

The closest points are thus $\displaystyle\left(\pm \frac{\sqrt{14}}{2},\frac{7}{2}\right)$

Comment: I'm sort of new to this site on the SE network–is it better to give hints or to give the answer altogether in an answer? I've seen many people here give hints more than actually solving the problem.

Comment: i think your hint was perfect. i just provided the rest in case the asker needed additional assistance. @AndrewLi

Comment: Thanks! I was finding the derivative wrong. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Anytime that you want 
to minimize the distance,
just minimize the distance squared.
The result will be the same.

In this case,
the distance squared from
$(0, 4)$
to
$(x, x^2)$
is

$\begin{array}\\
D
&=x^2+(x^2-4)^2\\
&=x^2+x^4-8x^2+16\\
&=x^4-7x^2+16\\
D'
&=4x^3-14x\\
&=0
\qquad\text{when}\\
0
&=4x^3-14x\\
\text{so}\\
x
&= 0\\
\text{or}\\
4x^2
&= 14\\
\text{so}\\
x
&= \pm\sqrt{\frac{7}{2}}\\
\end{array}
$

Now we have to check.

If
$x = 0$ then
$D = 16
$.

If
$x
=\pm\sqrt{\frac{7}{2}}
$
then
$x^2-4
=\frac{7}{2}-4
=-\frac14
$.

$\begin{array}\\
x^2 
&= \frac{7}{2}\\
x^4 
&= \frac{49}{4}\\
D
&=x^4-7x^2+16\\
&=\frac{49}{4}-7\frac{7}{2}+16\\
&=-\frac{49}{4}+16\\
&=\frac{64-49}{4}\\
&=\frac{15}{4}\\
&\lt 16\\
\end{array}
$

so the closest points are
$(\pm\sqrt{\frac{7}{2}}, 
-\frac14)$.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is the line joining the point $(0,4)$ will be normal to the curve. The reason is perpendicular is the shortest line joining two points.

Slope of any point $(h,h^2)$ lying on the curve is $2h$. Hence the slope of the normal is $\frac{-1}{2h}$. So the perpendicular has the given slope and passes through $(0,4)$. The equation of the normal is $2h(y-4)+x=0$. This line also passes through $(h,h^2)$.

Hence, $2h^3-8h+h=0$. Solve for $h$ and you have the answer.